# Onchange Event not fired

Tags: javascript, css, datetime, onchange

I want to check that whether the date is changed or not. When I am writing onchange event it is not getting fired. I have made a calendar using js. Below is the code:

```
<form:input path="date" autocomplete="off" htmlEscape="true" id="date" onchange="getDate()"></form:input> 
<A href="javascript:CssCalculator(date,'ddmmyyyy','arrow','true','24','true')" on`>
<IMG align="top" height=18 alt="Pick a date" src="images/calendar_button.gif" width=18></A></TD>
```

Onchange method is not called. It might be because its in different js. If I write onclcik event in  then it does not fetches the new date. It gives me the old date only.
Can anyone help me with this as I wanted to check that whether the date is changed or not.

Comment: Post your code first...

Comment: Which calendar apis you are using?

Comment: `java` `!=` `javascript`!.. same as _jar_ `!=` _Jarvis_

Comment: please make **jsfiddle** for more understanding

Comment: Start by posting the markup that the page receives, not what you write on the server.

Comment: I am able to see the code. @VaibhavKatole

Comment: @Jarvis, yeah you must be, but we are not able to see the code which is possibly creating any problem. You can provide the javascript code so that we can have a look into in order to help you. By the way, I asked 'Which calendar apis you are using?'.